# Storyboard editor layout confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, storyboard

I am having layout problems with the storyboard editor with a fairly simple screen.  I have a UIViewController to which I have added a 320x440 UIScrollView at 0,0 followed by a 320x20 UIProgressBar at 0,440.  It looks fine in Storyboard editor. I'm not entirely sure  how the 20 pixel status bar at the top of the screen is accommodated given the CGRect frame coordinates that Storyboard calculates.

On loading ( in `-(void)viewDidLoad` ), the UIScrollView frame seems to be set to **320x460**  pixels at 0,0 but the UIProgressBar is still 320x20 at 0,440.

When I add subviews to the UIScrollView, (UIImageViews in particular), they get stretched and get clipped on the screen because although the UIScrollView thinks it is 460 pixels high, it only has 440 pixels of screen to display in.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I have identified what was going on - there were a number of issues, nearly all to do with  mutually incompatible settings in storyboard attributes on various view controllers.

In summary, the main view controller containing the UIScrollView had the 'wants full screen' checkbox ticked - goodness knows how, but it appears that I had then gone through other views trying to compensate for that initial error by clipping, resizing, setting layout constraints etc. which resulted in rather confusing outcomes.

My advice would be to not touch ANYTHING in storyboard editor unless you know what it's effect will be - it is a dangerous place.  I found the issue by going back to basics and creating a trivially simple replication of my app and then observing the differences between that app and my own.  Sorry if I wasted anybody's time researching an answer.

Thanks